# Tensorflow uses CPU instead of GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nvidia-jetson

I'm working on a eyes tracking program using OpenCV, dlib and TensorFlow libraries, and I encounter some issues with a keras functions that using CPU instead of GPU.

**My setup**

I'm working on a Jetson AGX Xavier (Jetpack 4.4), running with Ubuntu and Cuda version 10.2.89 with a Ubuntu system.
The libraries was installed according these links:

- OpenCV: https://github.com/mdegans/nano_build_opencv
- Dlib: https://medium.com/@tran.minh.hoang.april/install-dlib-with-cuda-9-0-34c0f61fcf74
- Tensorflow + Keras: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/official-tensorflow-for-jetson-agx-xavier/65523

**The problem**

Well, my code runs well, so this is not a code issue. The problem is that one of his key function running on CPU instead of GPU, and strongly impact performances. This function is the [predict](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) function available in Tensorflow Keras.

I was able to monitor the GPU usage by using the`jtop` command, and it is close to 0. So i started digging why.

**The things I tried**

I started to make some digging by first checking the available devices for tensorflow. I ran the following command:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

And it gave me:

```
 [name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
...
name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
 ...
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
...
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
...
```

So I assumed that, at least, Tensorflow recognizes my GPU. Then I tried I made another test:

```
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
   print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
   print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

And it gave me:

```
Name: /device:GPU:0
```

So at this point everything seems ok. I pushed forward by activating the logs of Tensorflow :

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
```

I tracked down the two tensorflow functions I used in my program to check the detailed logs. The first used functions is called like this in my program. It is called just once:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('2018_12_17_22_58_35.h5', compile=True)
```

The associated logs are:

```
...
2020-10-15 22:40:31.591951: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-10-15 22:40:31.633533: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-10-15 22:40:31.636725: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-10-15 22:40:31.666428: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-10-15 22:40:31.670077: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
...
```

So it appears that this function uses GPU. The other function, predict, is called like this:

```
pred_l = model.predict(eye_input)
```

The logs are:

```
...
RepeatDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-10-15 22:40:38.143067: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op ZipDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-10-15 22:40:38.161602: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op ParallelMapDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-10-15 22:40:38.163806: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op ModelDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-10-15 22:40:38.179115: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op RangeDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
...
```

In this case, the logs say this function use CPU, which is coherent with my initial analysis. Since this is function is call in the while loop (to apply it to everey images), it is crutial to run it on GPU to increase performance. I tried to force GPU usage by using

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0)
```

But it still not working.

Since I followed the official NVIDA instructions to install the lib, and since [official website](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu) indicate that tensorflow will use GPU by default if it is available, i don't think it is an installation problem.

Is anyone have to solutions to this ?

Thanks.

Comment: what environment are you working in?

Comment: You cannot infer if predict is running in the GPU by looking at the ops like that, some ops will always run on the GPU since they deal with data loading and uploading to the GPU, so you are chasing a ghost. It is likely that the model is too small to benefit from GPU acceleration, depends on a lot of factors you are not mentioning

Comment: Thank for your answer. Do you mean that if my model is to small (currently 12 MB) it will not benefit GPU? Is there a way to force it ? Because the performance are currently very bad.